# How to find a string pattern that isn't in a tag in a BeautifulSoup object

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Problem: My program processes HTML test reports and lists header information and pass/fail results.  Some of the information in the report needed for the header is text that is not in a tag so the find() and find_all() methods aren't applicable.
When Python prints a BeautifulSoup object, it looks like text but you can't do simple pattern matches on it.  And all the BeautifulSoup methods seem to assume that everything is a tag of some kind.

I won't list all the things I tried because I resolved the issue.

Resolution: Cast the BeautifulSoup object as a string first, then Python pattern matching works.

I'm posting this because I spent a *lot* of time searching for an answer to this problem and didn't find any information.  And it would be interesting to know of other ways to do this.

```
# testReport type is BeautifulSoup
s = str(testReport)
if '_Tray5_' in s:
    Tray = '5'
```

Comment: what do you mean it's not in a tag? if it's html, it has to be within *some* tag

Comment: are you aware of `soup.findAll(text="your pattern")` ? also please provide a real world example as we can't work blind here ! check [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: It's between <\P> and <P>.  So it's not encased in a tag, right?

Comment: I tried a lot of things, including the soup.findAll(text="pattern") method, which didn't work. It's possible that I misused it.  It didn't seem productive to list all the things that didn't work.  I can go back and try findAll and see if it works.  But a string cast is easier. This entry is mostly to help someone trying to find a way to make it work, as I was earlier this week.

Comment: If it is between those p tags it is part of a parent tag.